# Flutter Phone Number - intl_phone_number package

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, phone-number

```
  InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
          onInputChanged: onInputChanged,
          cursorColor: kDarkGreyColor,
          initialValue: phoneNumber, //+961 or 961
          hintText: 'Phone Number',
...
```

I want to set the initial value of the flag selector to my country +961
However initial value is not working? How do i set the initial value country code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpzJv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked as follows

```
initialValue: PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'LB', dialCode:'+961'),
```

...

Answer (score 0):

When you create a phone number add an Iso code like the following

```
PhoneNumber number = PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'LB');//lebanon's iso code
```

Comment: yes i tried that but isoCode on its own didn't seem to work, I had to put both the dialCode and the isoCode.... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Value addition in @Lou's answer, You can set a starting country that corresponds to the current region of the phone.

```
 initialValue: PhoneNumber(
    isoCode: Platform.localeName.split('_').last,
 ),
```

For more information check at https://github.com/natintosh/intl_phone_number_input/issues/155